# ¿Se usa en España la palabra "Tramitología"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, significado, hispanoamérica

Leyendo un artículo, me encontré con una palabra que, cuando menos me causó cierta perplejidad. ¿Sería una errata, o en efecto la expresión existe? Ante la duda, acudí al Diccionario, y allí estaba.

> **tramitología**. 1. f. Col. Arte o ciencia de resolver, perfeccionar o facilitar los trámites.

No me parece una definición ni estricta ni precisa, y desde luego poco o nada despejaba mi duda inicial. Por otro lado: ¿no peca de exagerada? ¿Arte? ¿Ciencia?

Comoquiera que se trata de una expresión no utilizada en España ---nunca la había oído ni leído--- me dirigí al *Diccionario de americanismos*, donde se detalla y amplía un poco más. Y desde luego me aclaró por fin las dudas:

> 1. f. CR, Co. Conjunto de normativas relacionadas con los trámites que deben hacerse para llevar a cabo una gestión administrativa o de otro tipo.
> 2. CR, Co. Empleo exagerado de trámites para realizar una gestión administrativa o de otro tipo. pop ^ desp. ◆ tramitomanía.

En cualquier caso, sigue llamándome la atención, pues a pesar deser un término sancionado por la Academia me parece una especie de *palabro*, que bien hubiera podido atribuírsele al gran **Forges**.

Mi pregunta es si alguno de vosotros la conoce y la ha visto en algún texto.

---

**Fuentes**

[Tramitología, simplificación de procesos administrativos y reingeniería de negocios](http://www.cic.ipn.mx/aguzman/papers/114%20Tramitologia.%20Simplificacion%20de%20procesos%20administrativos.pdf)

https://www.asale.org/damer/tramitolog%C3%ADa

Comment: I vote to close this question because I don't think it solves any problems related to the Spanish language to ask if someone knows a word, especially when the question includes its definitions.

Comment: Mi intención es saber si alguien conoce esta palabra y su uso, ya que me parece curioso no haberla oído nunca. En España tenemos "burocracia", que es la que me parece más se le aproxima. Pero "tramitología, tal como la define el DLE, no da la misma idea ni definición.

Comment: He visto preguntas con la misma intencionalidad, en la que se ofrecía la definición, y no obstante se preguntaba por sus usos. Y aun así no se cerraron, porque el conocimiento se produce de muchas formas, una de ellas comprobando la gran diversidad de un idioma.

Comment: De hecho, en la Ayuda, bajo el apartado "¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?" aparece "Usos, elección de palabras, gramática y pronunciación ". Puesto que mi pregunta tiene que ver con "Usos", es en mi opinión On-topic, y no Off-topic.

Comment: Tengo un amigo griego que dejó estudios classicos, se compró un restaurante y dice que está haciendo un negocio de hamburgolia. :)

Comment: Me acaban de decir que en Argentina se usa la expresión "Tramiterío".

Answer (score 1):

En la página castellano.org, aparece [esa consulta](https://www.elcastellano.org/roc%C3%ADo-carrillo), y dice lo siguiente:

> Palabra sobre la que consulta:
> Tramitología
>
> Consulta:
> ¿Es correcto decir tramitología?
>
> Respuesta:
> Sí, es un término usual en algunos países de América, como en Costa Rica y en Colombia. Se emplea con el doble significado de ‘conjunto de normativas relacionadas con los trámites que deben hacerse para llevar a cabo una gestión administrativa o de otro tipo’ y, en sentido despectivo y en el lenguaje popular, ‘empleo exagerado de trámites para realizar una gestión administrativa o de otro tipo’ (Diccionario de americanismos, ASALE, 2010).

---

Así, ante la expansión del español y variedades en la locución de una misma palabra, la RAE desde hace ya un tiempo recoge muchos americanismos, según ella para dar más uniformidad a la lengua. Sin embargo, tampoco quiere quedarse detrás de otras lenguas como el francés o el inglés. Por ejemplo, mientras el español cuenta con unas 150.000 palabras aproximadamente el idioma inglés lo dobla, y es porque incorpora muchas variantes de países de la Commonwealth, por lo que de alguna manera responde a esa carrera por incorporar "nuevas" expresiones.

Comment: En algunos países de Latinoamérica sabemos que se usa (yo mismo lo comenté en la pregunta. Pero mi pregunta es "si se usa en España".

Comment: En cualquier caso, gracias por el aporte, porque no conocía esa página.

Comment: Yo no la he oído todavía, ni siquiera en las gestorías.

Comment: https://www.asale.org/damer/tramitolog%C3%ADa , cierto